# What does '.' signify in c as argument to opendir?

Tags: c, operating-system

"This is the code. What is the meaning of '.' inside "opendir('.')" Does it specifies to the current directory?"

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <dirent.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry 

// opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type.  
DIR *dr = opendir("."); 

if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory 
{ 
    printf("Could not open current directory" ); 
    return 0; 
} 


while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL) 
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name); 

closedir(dr);     
return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
DIR *dr = opendir(".");
```

`.` represents the *current directory* and `..` represents the *parent directory*, here `opendir()` tries to open the current directory & if success it return a pointer to the directory stream.

from the manual page of [opendir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html)

> The `opendir()` function shall open a directory stream corresponding
>   to the directory named by the `dirname` argument. The ***directory
>   stream is positioned at the first entry.***

On most of linux machines, first two entries in a directory are current `.` and parent `..`. If you run a `ls` command in a given directory it shows like

```
[root@try]# ls -lia
total 28
425985 drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Jan 30 10:29 .       <--- current dir inode
393284 drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 20480 Jan 30 10:28 ..      <--- parent dir inode
407821 -rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Jan 30 10:29 demo.c
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really programming-related, but more OS-related.

On most operating systems the filesystem have the concept of parent directory and current directory.

The parent directory is commonly using the notation `..`, while the current directory is using the notation `.`.

So what `opendir(".")` will do is to open the current directory.

---

And as mentioned in a comment, the "current" directory doesn't have to be the directory where the executable program is residing. It's the current [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) for the process, which could be different. It depends on how and where the program was started, and if the program changes its own working directory (which the program in the question doesn't).

Comment: Note that lots of people incorrectly assume that the current directory is the directory in which the program resides, but that is not necessarily the case.